# Changing Ford e4od to 4r100

Tags: electrical, ford, automatic-transmission

e4od is a gear driven speed sensor/ 4r100 is reading directly off tail shaft and signal is much faster causing speed to read much faster. Is there a way to put an in-line adjustable type signal changer that will slow down signal?